# Having trouble calling a method in a different class with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, class, methods, junit

Okay so I'm doing some practice with JUnit Test cases and I'm trying to call a method from a different class in Java, but I can't figure it out. The classes are in different SOURCE FOLDERS so not sure if that could be a reason?

Below is a small snippet of the code, with the constructors and an example of how I'm trying to call the method.

```
package common;

public class MathTest {

    @Test
    public void test1(){

            if (mMultiply(5, 6)== 30){
                System.out.println("mMultiply Test has passesd");
            } else {
                System.out.println("mMultiply Test has failed");
                fail("Multiply failed for inputted parameters. ");
```

And now here's the the other class with the method I'm trying to call 
package common;

```
public class math {

    public static int mMultiply(int x, int y){
    return x*y;

}
```

Comment: what is the class name that the mMultiply method is in? Assuming its 'Math' than you need to call 'Math.mMultiply'

Comment: Since the classes are in different folders, pay attention to the package declarations - it should match the folder structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's a static method, just import the class in your JUnit file test. Then use the [`Assert class`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) of JUnit to test your function. In this case, use [`assertEquals`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28long,%20long%29).
So I would rewrite the test as :

```
@Test
public void test1(){
    assertEquals(math.mMultiply(5, 6),30);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm new at Java and (programming in general) and just had a huge project thrown at me! I'm learning fast though and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell your method which class the static method is in i.e.:

```
if (math.mMultiply(5, 6)== 30){
        System.out.println("mMultiply Test has passesd");
    }
```

Incidentally, all Java classes should start with a capital letter, and there's already a core Java class called Math, so you might want to find another name.

Answer (score 1):

try `math.mMultiply` It is a static method so you must specify in which class it resides

Answer (score 1):

When you call `mMultiply(5,6)`, do it like this: `math.mMultiply(5,6)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a **static** method, you call it with its class name before it:

```
math.mMultiply(value1, value2).
```

Also, check the java code writing manuals. Class names begin with capital letter, so I would change the class of the `math` class to `Math`.

Comment: Watch out though because it conflicts with java.Math which you may want to use in the same file...